# Get size of SVN branch before checkout

Tags: svn, cornerstone

I would like to know the size of SVN branch before Checkout that branch in my Mac. So is there any way to know the size of branch in Cornerstone or via terminal commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Only approximately
- Only in console (but I don't know Cornerstone at all)
- Only with some handwork

Using `svn ls` for the root of remote branch URL (see [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) for the proper options: `-v` `-R`), you can calculate size of all files in branch. **Beware:** real space requirements will be (slightly) bigger, because uou have to store also some *metadata* in `.svn` folder in your WC